# Is there an iPhone 5 simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

My hard drive crashed, and I had to re-install all the development software.

It seems like when I create a new project, it is targeted for the iPhone 5 (The UI editor has a taller screen in the layout) but the simulator is an iPhone 4 (the screen is not as long)  All so When I layout the UI in Xcode, the simulator sometimes draws things at different vertical positions.

Is there a way to get a simulator for iPhone 5?
Can you create a project that has it so the UI editor is targeted for the older iPhone, iPhone 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select either of the simulators you want for your project:

[image]

[image]

`iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)` is for `iPhone 4` or `iPhone 4S` and `iPhone Retina (4-inch)` is for `iPhone 5`.

Comment: You do not need to download additional simulators to solve this question. Downloading is only needed to get simulator support for other versions of iOS.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, as you may notice, that's what I've mentioned in the last sentence of my answer. (:

Comment: Then what was the point of the 1st part of your answer? It's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @rmaddy Edit applied!

Comment: Hi,I have xcode 4.6 and only have options for iPad and iPhone

Comment: @Tedpottel Ok, then set the deployment and build target to 5.0, and from the Simulator's top menu, go to `Hardware > Devices` and see if you have `iPhone Retina 4"` there.