# Can't run app in Simulator, only device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

first i'm new in the world of xcode and app development.

I just wrote a small app and made some project changes (don't know what exactly) and know, 
i only can select my device if i try to run my app. it works fine on the device, but i want to run it on the simulator to test the other display sizes.

I tried to change the deployment target to 5.0, but the simulator doesn't appear.

Comment: does your app require a camera?

Comment: You made changes but you don't know what? Are you using version control? That would help you see the changes.

Comment: Is there an error you get, or do you only see your device under the choices for devices, or what? You don't give us exactly _why_ you cannot run on the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the deployment target to run the project in simulator. You just need to select the simulator you want to run, to use it.

Here's how:
[Is there an iPhone 5 simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291694/is-there-an-iphone-5-simulator/20291852#20291852)

Try to search and read all similar questions and answers and documentations before asking a question.